# HTML - Issue with form submission

Tags: html, forms

Issue with submitting form, I don't see anything wrong with the `form` section.

This is an example of my code, The ticket number and user ID is being pushed into from MYSQL. When it gets to the server side after submitting, I am getting only 2 of 21 items. The `readonly` is only on the top 2 items, the rest is entered by end user.

```
<form action="<?php echo $NAV_includes_Research_Upload; ?>" method="POST">
    <table class="Table_Center">
      <tr>
        <td>Ticket number:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="ticket" class="all" value="<?php echo "1"; ?>" readonly></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>User ID:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="user" class="all" value="<?php echo "test"; ?>" readonly>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Site:</td>
        <td><input type="url" id="website" class="all" autofocus required <?php if ($testing === 'ON') {echo 'value="http://www.google.com"';}?>></td>
      </tr>
</table>
  <table class="Table_Center">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" class="f_right" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</form>
```

---

Thank you, it was the name section that was missing.
I will have to remember that.

Comment: Based on your code, I can figure out that you may not be getting any data from form in the Action file. Is that correct?

Comment: Please post your action code as well.

Comment: When it gets over to the Action page, its showing 2 items from form were submitted out of 21 items.

Comment: In your form code, I am unable to find 'name' attribute of input fields. In form Post, values entered by the user and submitted are called by the name attribute. This is what I can figure out from the information you shared. If this doesn't help, try to post your action code as well.

Comment: Thank you  Mohammed, that worked.

Comment: Glad to know this. Happy coding!

Comment: I have added the solution that worked for you as an answer. Please accept it as the answer in order to close the question properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form code, I am unable to find `name` attribute of input fields. In an HTML form Post, values entered by the user and submitted are called by the `name` attribute.